# Eclipse juno won't hit breakpoints in GWT server side code running in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt, remote-debugging

I'm running Vogella's tutorial on GWT (http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html) and my Eclipse Juno installation on OSX is not able to hit a breakpoint in the server-side service module implementation java class MyUserServiceImpl.

I've linked an external (not workspace) installation of Tomcat 7 with my Eclipse, from which I am able to successfully start and stop the server.  I can see during server startup that the port 8000 is setup for attachment (by adding to the VM args: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n).  I appear to be able to attach to port 8000 using Remote Debugging on the localhost url in Eclipse.

Any suggestions on why I'm not able to hit the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that instead of debugging it as a Remote Java Application, debugging it as a Web Application works.

Still need to ensure that its in fact getting deployed to the correct tomcat installation directory.  I've unchecked "Run built-in server" in the Debug Configuration for the Web Application type project.  I've also ensured that eclipse has taken control of the tomcat installation identified in preferences.  Manually setting the directory was not allowed as I had identified it separately in eclipse as THE tomcat installation dir.